# How to set multiple files as program arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I've got this problem. I have a lot of files in one folder. I also have three programs executable in shell.
What I need to do is to write a script, which will take all files from the folder, which end with character '_' and send them one by one through all three program as listed below"

Files which end with a character '_' should be set as an input option of program1. The program has to be run twice with different options.

```
./program1 -i "fileXXX.14_";
./program1 -i "fileXXX.14_" -n N;
```

the program1 creates two files - "fileXXX.14O" and "fileXXX.14N".

Then the script needs to pass these two files as arguments of the second program aswell. I also need to set an option for an output filename.

```
./program2 -o "fileXXX.pos" "fileXXX.14O" "fileXXX.14N";
```

Finally the script needs to run the third program with "fileXXX.pos" as an input option

```
./program3 -i "fileXXX.pos" ;
```

Ideally files fileXXX.14N, fileXXX.14O and fileXXX.pos would be deleted after this action.

Mabye somthing like this would do the trick,

```
find . -name '*_' -exec  ./sbf2rin -o copy -f `echo {}` \; -exec ....
```

but i have no idea how to pass other arguments or options, based on found file, afterwards.

Any ideas how to do this? It would help me so much... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% on what you want to do but this may work for you

```
for i in *_;do
    ./program1 -i "$i"
    ./program1 -i "$i" -n N
    ./program2 -o "${i%.}".{pos,140,14N}
    ./program3 -i "${i%.}.pos" ;
    rm "${i%.}".{pos,140,14N}
 done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works great. But for some reason the dot behind percetn sign in ${i%.} doesnt represent any sing but is represented as a regular dot... so I have to write something like ${i%.14_} to make it work. This isnt the best way how to do it because the "14" in the end isnt guaranteed :/